# Lasso Regression glmnet - error regarding the input data

Tags: r, glmnet, lasso-regression

I try to fit a Lasso regression model using glmnet(). As I have never worked with Lasso regression before, I tried to get along with tutorials but when applying the model, it always results with the following error:

```
Error in lognet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,: 
one multinomial or binomial class has 1 or 0 observations; not allowed
```

Working with the dataset from this question (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72251/an-example-lasso-regression-using-glmnet-for-binary-outcome) it seems that the dependent variable, the y, has to consist only of 0 and 1. Whenever I set one of the observation values of y to 2 or anything else than 0 or 1, it results in this error.

This is my code:

```
lambdas_to_try <- 10^seq(-3, 5, length.out = 100)

x_vars <- as.matrix(data.frame(data$x1, data$x2, data$x3))
lasso_cv <- cv.glmnet(x_vars, y=as.factor(data$y), alpha = 1, lambda = lambdas_to_try, family = "binomial", nfolds = 10)

x_vars_2 <- model.matrix(data$y ~ data$x1 + data$x2 + data$x3)[, -1]
lasso_cv_2 <- cv.glmnet(x_vars, y=as.factor(data$y), alpha = 1, lambda = lambdas_to_try, family = "binomial", nfolds = 10)
```

And this is how my dataset looks like:

[image]

The problem is, that in my data, the y variable represents the number of crimes, so it has integer values between 0 and 1000. I cannot set the value to 0 and 1 only. How does it work to use these data to apply a Lasso regression?

Comment: Please show the command you are using, not just the error. But it sounds like you are using logistic regression (GLM with binomial error structure) which requires binary data. If your data is binary, don't do that. Perhaps regular linear regression, or perhaps Poisson regression, since your data sounds like count data.

Comment: If you show the code you are using, we can help you with how to change it.

Comment: I added the code and a picture showing how my code looks like. But I need to make a Lasso regression, I do not have binary data, my data are count data.

Comment: Change `family = "binomial"` to `family = "poisson"`.

Comment: When changing the family to poisson, it results in another error, although I do not have any negative values (I double checked my data). Any idea?

Error in if (any(y < 0)) stop("negative responses encountered;  not permitted for Poisson family") : 
  Missing value, where TRUE/FALSE is necessary
Warning:
  In Ops.factor(y, 0) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: Don't factor your data - it's not categorical. Replace `as.factor(data$y)` with `data$y`. If you encounter more problems, instead of solving them one error at a time please post a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gregor noted, what you have is count data, and it should be regression and not classification. Using an example dataset, this is how you can implement it:

```
library(MASS)
library(glmnet)
data(Insurance)
```

Your response variable should be numeric:

```
str(Insurance)
'data.frame':   64 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ District: Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Group   : Ord.factor w/ 4 levels "<1l"<"1-1.5l"<..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ Age     : Ord.factor w/ 4 levels "<25"<"25-29"<..: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
 $ Holders : int  197 264 246 1680 284 536 696 3582 133 286 ...
 $ Claims  : int  38 35 20 156 63 84 89 400 19 52 ...
```

Now we set the predictors and response variables:

```
y = Insurance$Claims
X = model.matrix(Claims ~ .,data=Insurance)
```

Run a cv to find the best lambda (if you don't know your L1 norm):

```
fit = cv.glmnet(x=X,y=y,family="poisson")
pred = predict(fit,X,s=fit$lambda.1se)
```

The prediction is in log scale, so to compare with your actual

```
plot(log(y),pred,xlab="log (actual)",ylab="log (predicted)")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! Do I understand it correctly that fit = ... finds the best lambda value and uses the best lambda value then in the final model (pred)? How can one interpret the plot? Should it show the lambda value or if there is a regression between y and the x variables?

Comment: The last plot shows you what your predictions look like.. basically how it is fitted , or whether it is fitted correctly.. in this example, it is general ok

Comment: yes, if you use cv.glmnet you used cross-validation to find the best lambda value. And you can use it in the prediction. Otherwise it will return predictions for all lambdas

Comment: So does the last plot show the predicted values (log predicted) by the model and the actual values (log actual) of the data? Considering that all values are in log scale. 
Assuming the prediction would be 100% correclty, would the values all lie on a line?
And do the axes have to show the same values? With my data I have for the x-axis values between 2 and 5, on the y-axis 14 to 26.

Comment: it should still lie close to the line, in log scale. It cannot be that different. you should check your code. in any case, if this is an additional question consider posting it on stats exchange

Comment: or check out https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html for a guide or overview on how to fit. From what I can see, the poisson distribution should work for count data. If you have other issues i suspect it is related to statistics